# How to connect Oracle database to JMeter if we have service name instead of SID?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jmeter

I'm using Oracle with JMeter and instead of using SID we use service name. I get this error:

```
Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor)
```

My JMeter configuration:

```
 jdbc:oracle:thin:@<hostname>:<port>:<serviceName>
 oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

[image]

Comment: can you pls try this jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host:port/service and set max number of connections to 0

Comment: nothing's happen still getting the ORA-00911: invalid character

Answer (score 1):

Your database URL in your configuration needs to be:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@<hostname>:<port>/<serviceName>
```

A colon before the last element indicates you are passing a SID. A slash indicates you are passing a service name.

From the screenshot you added later and the error you got next, you also need to change the isolation level from `DEFAULT` to `TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITED`, and you need to change the validation query from `select 1` to `select 1 from dual`. Make sure you do not add a semicolon on the end of that query. (A semicolon is a statement separator is many clients, it is not part of a single SQL statement, and including it in a JDBC call will give you an ORA-00911 error).

Comment: i tried jdbc:oracle:thin:@<hostname>:<port>/<serviceName> and jdbc:oracle:thin:@//<hostname>:<port>/<serviceName> i get same error Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (READ_COMMITTED and SERIALIZABLE are the only valid transaction levels)

Comment: @JhengIbasco - how is that the same error? That seems to be something else in your config. Maybe ask a new question about that error, showing your full config. I have no idea where it would be getting he transaction level from, or what value it's trying to use.

Comment: Did you use select 1 from dual in the validation query?

Comment: here is my config: transaction isolationL=DEFAULT, Validation Query = Select 1, DBURL= jdbc:oracle:thin:@<hostname>:<port>/<serviceName>, Driver class = oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

Comment: OK, so change the isolation from `DEFAULT` to `READ_COMMITTED`?

Comment: if my transaction isolation = TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITED and the validation query = select 1 from dual the error isORA-00911: invalid character while, if my  transaction isolation = TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITED and the validation query = Select 1 the error is Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected )

Comment: It has to be `select 1 from dual` for Oracle - make sure you don't have a semicolon at the end of that statement though, as that would cause that error.

Comment: yes already did that but i got ORA-00911: invalid character error

Comment: Did you try `select 1 from dual` (which is OK) or `select 1 from dual;` (which is not OK because of the semicolon)?

Comment: yes i do not have semi colon at the end i still always getting the same error?

Comment: That looks OK. Can you check you're using the correct JDBC driver, and that it's a version supported by the version of JMeter and the database you're running this against?

Comment: Im currently using the updated jmeter which is 3.2 and i tried also in my 3.1 but getting the same error. I will check maybe there is a problem to the driver I'm currently using. Will try to download another one. Do you have any suggestions for the best link where i can download the driver?

Comment: In a comment on the other answer you said "i only have select * from tableName;" - which does have an illegal semicolon! You implied the error was from the validation query, but it looks like it is from your actual code instead, and not related to the configuration now.

Comment: Yup that query is in my jdbc sampler. And i think once i remove the semicolon at the end of the query it will have an error. Is that right? However, i think my jdbc configuration seems OK now. What do you think?

Comment: Why will it have an error after you remove the semicolon? Have you tried it and that is what happens - in which case what error? Does the table you're querying exist or are you using a default dummy query? What happens if you change your 'sampler' to the same `select * from dual`?

Comment: after i execute my query which is in the JDBC Sampler without semicolon at the end like "select * from tableName" i got closed socket error and takes too much time before it respond. However, if i put on my sampler like "select * from tableName;" i got invalid character. The table i am querying is the actual database that we are using.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your JDBC URL like:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@<hostname>:<port>/<serviceName>
                                   ^slash instead of colon should be here
```

References:

- [JDBC - Oracle FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC)
- [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter)

Comment: i tried jdbc:oracle:thin:@<hostname>:<port>/<serviceName> and jdbc:oracle:thin:@//<hostname>:<port>/<serviceName> i get same error Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (READ_COMMITTED and SERIALIZABLE are the only valid transaction levels)

Comment: Change **Transaction Isolation** to `TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED` or `TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE` in the [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration). Also change validation query to `select 1 from dual`

Comment: yes already did thet but the error is ORA-00911: invalid character im using 3.2 version of jmeter

Comment: show your jdbc connection configuration and jdbc request screenshots

Comment: i am new to stack and when i tried the ctrl+g it just displayed the find bar. may i know how to upload photo here?

Comment: I have no idea, most probably you have an error either in JDBC url or in SQL query itself

Comment: I tried to execute my query in sqlDeveloper tool and i get the correct output. Also, i only have select * from tableName; so I doubt that there is an error w/ my script. I will try to download another driver. Do you have any suggestions for the best link where i can download the driver? Thank you.

Comment: The best option will be extracting the driver from the Oracle installation. Alternative option would be downloading the matching driver from Oracle website

Comment: yup.that is the driver i am currently using.

Comment: i tried ojdbc6, 7 and 8 driver in jmeter 3.1 and 3.2 versions and i got the same error which is ORA-00911: invalid character.

Answer (score 0):

When connecting to an Oracle database, database server will have a configuration file (tnsnames.ora), that informs the server about NET_SERVICE_NAMES which are valid database connections.

By default, this file is located at ORACLE_HOME/network/admin and should contain entry like :

myDatabaseNetService =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)(QUEUESIZE = 100))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = bookstore.company.com)
    )
  )

Use myDatabaseNetService as SERVICE_NAME in connection string.

Comment: replacing his database url to this also should work: jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address=(host=localhost)(protocol=tcp)(port={port no}))(connect_data=(service_name = {service_name})))

Answer (score 0):

Thank You guys for helping me. So appreciated. So what i did to resolve my problem is i just downgrade my JMeter version to 2.13 and the configurations are:

Transaction Isolation: TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITED
Validation Query: select 1 from or Select 1
Database URL: jdbc:oracle:thin:@:/
JDBC Driver Class: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
JDBC Sampler: There should no semicolon at the end of the query
Oracle driver: ojdbc7 in oracle website
path of driver: lib/ext